# How to format cells from a csv or xlsx file in excel with an ISO_4217 currency that can be reused for calculation

Tags: excel, csv, xlsx, currency-formatting

**Issue description**
I am exporting a table containing strings, numeric values, percentages and currencies to a `csv` or `xlsx` file for example:

```
CH0038863350,nominatives Nestlé SA,1,CHF 848.48,SHARE,6.72%
US0378331005,Stammaktien Apple Inc. 2,USD 118.64,SHARE,-55.13%
```

The issue that I have with the import in excel is, that it recognizes and formats some values as `Currency` and other values are just in the `General` format.

I would like to format the values in such a way, that I can reuse them for further calculation.
The currency values are in the [ISO_4217](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) format.

After some reasearch I have found out, that this is not so easy to do, because excel uses currency symbols `($,£,€, etc.)` internally.

---

**Questions**
Do I have to convert my data to a specific format in order to work? Can I setup a custom format for my cell values that will support the desired format and then can still be used as a number for further calculation?

A simple workaround would be to export the numbers and the currency into two columns.

What would you suggest?

**EDIT: The point was, that I wanted the format to be in one cell not in two (split of currency and value). The latter is fairly simple.**

Comment: Personally I'd probably split the field in question, with one having the currency name, and the other the numeric value. If you want both to display in the same column, you can set up a custom number format.

Comment: @eirikdaude Hmm sounds reasonable and how would the data have to look like to support such a custom format? And would it work with a csv import or do I have to provide a xlsx in order for custom formats to be recognized?

Comment: How do you import the data?

Comment: @eirikdaude I do "open with excel" or I import it with the "import from text" inside excel. Whatever works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the "Data Ribbon" and select "From Text/CSV". Choose your file and select "comma" as delimiter.

[image]

Next choose "transform data", highlight the column with the currency values, and choose "split column by delimiter".

[image]

Click "Close and load".

Finally, if you don't want your table to stay connected to the csv-file, right-click on the query which was created and choose "delete"

[image]

There might be simpler ways to do this as well, but I think this should work for you.

Comment: I can export the currency and the value as separate values so I don't have to do the modification even. I really loved if I could do it in one cell, but I feel like this is what I will end up with. It is definitely a solution, but not quite what I wanted. I will wait a bit for other answers. I might accept it later.

Comment: You can probably use something like `=concat(D2;E2)`, or if all values in the column are in the same currency you could create a custom number format, but I don't think there are any obvious way to have it all. Choosing that column 4 is text in the second step might work, but then it'll be hard to work with the values in that column as numbers. @F.Müller

Comment: I've been looking for other options and have been left a little bit disappointed. I find it strange that excel does not support such a feature - I mean its all about numbers isn't it? Anyway, thank you for your effort. I exported the values separately now, as I had in mind when I wrote the question (fallback).